# robocopy: how to make automatic monitoring and copy contents of a folder when anything changes with robocopy?

Tags: robocopy

in the source (parent) folder, there are certain contents (subfolders, files), changes will happen in these contents time to time. my idea is to monitor this parent folder with the help of robocopy and look for changes every 2 minutes. If changes occurs, copy changes to the destination folder. Below is my command in robocopy:

> **robocopy** *C:\Users\username\Desktop\test_robocopy\source* **/E**  *C:\Users\username\Desktop\test_robocopy\destination* **/mot:2**

At first it detects changes automatically and the command runs and files are copied from source to destination. The problem is that, it is not automated afterwards, it needs key interrupt for example "hit enter" in the terminal and then it runs through. What am I missing above in the robocopy command to make it automated so that no other intervention needed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you expect, but I think it accomplishes what you want.
I have based my script on the one found [here](https://superuser.com/a/891766).
This is a powershell script, so you need to save it as .ps1 and run it.
You can check the original answer for more details.

Basically what it does is to watch for file changes and trigger robocopy whenever this change happens.

In your case, I think you basically need to raise the wait time

```
$block = {    
    function Do-Something
    {
        param ($message, $event)
        # function to call when event is raised
        # do a robocopy or whatever

        foreach ($folder in $watchedFolder) {
        robocopy $folder ("o:\" + $folder.Replace("C:\Users\User\", "")) /MIR /e #here I'm using a string replace so I keep only the
        #name of the folder to be mirrored, not the whole path - I'm sure there's a way to do this without the string replacement but
        #I still didn't have time to find out how.
        }
    }

    $watchedFolder = ("C:\Users\User\Desktop\a", "C:\Users\User\Desktop\b") #here I have created an array instead of only one folder.
    #This wai I can simply add all my folders here and when my "foreach" is fired above, it will run for all my folders
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = $watchedFolder

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier File.Created -Action { Do-Something "Created" $event }
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Deleted -SourceIdentifier File.Deleted -Action { Do-Something "Deleted" $event }
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed -SourceIdentifier File.Changed -Action { Do-Something "Changed" $event }
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Renamed -SourceIdentifier File.Renamed -Action { Do-Something "Renamed" $event }
}

$encodedBlock = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($block))

Start-Process PowerShell.exe -argumentlist '-WindowStyle Hidden', '-NoExit', '-EncodedCommand', $encodedBlock
    while ($true) {sleep 5} #here the script sleeps 5 miliseconds and repeats all again - That way, I can listen to file changes and copy
    #the changes instantly. In your case, you can use sleep -Seconds  120
```